# operation status vs exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I'm curious as to when use operation status and when exceptions. Say I have a class `TextProcessor` with methods `getText()`, `processText()` and `sendText()`. All these methods perform operations on private data of the class. I need to make sure that all operations go smoothly. I've got two options - each method can return operation status (0 - success, >0 error codes) or throw exception inside a method. It seems that exceptions is more convinient way to control method's execution, because I'd need to do the following when operation statuses are returned:

```
$result = textProcessor->getText();
if ( $result !== 0 ) {
    return $result;
}

$result = textProcessor->processText();
if ( $result !== 0 ) {
    return $result;
}

$result = textProcessor->sendText();
if ( $result !== 0 ) {
    return $result;
}
```

or this way

```
if ( textProcessor->getText() !== 0 && textProcessor->processText() !== 0 && textProcessor->sendText() !== 0 ) {
    return processingErrors::textProcessorError;
}
```

It all seems much simpler with exceptions:

```
try {
    textProcessor->getText();
    textProcessor->processText();
    textProcessor->sendText();
} catch (textProcessorException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

1) So which is better to use in my situation - operation statuses or exceptions?
2) In general, when do I use operation statuses (return codes) and when exceptions?

Comment: Exceptions should be thrown in exceptional circumstances: file doesn't exist when it should, database connection has evaporated, etc

Comment: I think second way is better.

Comment: @MarkBaker, is empty text being passed to a method considered exception?

Comment: Empty text will depend on the method and what it's supposed to do

Comment: @JasonOOO, do you mean with exceptions? Why do you think it's better?

Comment: @MarkBaker: I meant this `if ( textProcessor->getText() !== 0 && textProcessor->processText() !== 0 && ...`

Comment: @MarkBaker, the method takes one parameter $word and uses it as part of sql query. If this parameter is passed empty, should I return error status code or throw exception?

Comment: Well you should validate that the string has a value first; but that isn't really an exception, more like a simple error (invalid data) - an exception would be "database doesn't exist"

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any resource where I can read about the matter? I've browsed the web but I haven't found anything about error codes practices.

Comment: @MarkBaker, can you elaborate on why the approach with error codes is better?

Comment: Because they're errors, not exceptions - exceptions should be for the truly abnormal events, not simple validations... the purpose of exceptions is for handling emergency situations... they're the equivalent of calling the emergency services because your partner has just had a heart attack, not because the cat has got stuck up a tree for the seventh time today

Comment: Ok, thanks! It seems that this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2392502/2545680) suggests that exceptions is a better choice.

Comment: That's his opinion: I'd disagree.... and your question was asking for an opinion - I've tried to explain what I believe and why: but you pick whatever you like because there is no definitive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are best used when some requirements of operation is unexpectedly absent. For example, I expect to be able to connect to a database. If I cannot, then I cannot serve the application even in a degraded state. I throw an exception saying so because I cannot continue. If I could continue, that might be something I log but not throw an exception for.

That said, using them for control flow, for me, is totally valid. Having all the return codes as you describe seems less than optimal and not as readable as the exception option. When code is not readable it is not as easily maintained.